# EntityValidationErrors Reporting Incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a case where entities.SaveChanges() is throwing a DbEntityValidationException and stating

> The AValue field is required", however the AValue property has been populated.

Is there something else that can be checked to determine why this is throwing this error.

The basic code throwing the error:

```
try
{
   var entities = new MyEntities();
   var item = (from i in entities.Item
               where i.Id == 1
               select i).First();
   item.AValue = "NewValue";
   entities.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException exception)
{
   var report = exception.Message();
}
```

I've done a bit of digging and in the catch have put:

```
var x = item.AValue; // and it shows "NewValue"
```

and

```
var message = new StringBuilder();

 foreach (var entityValidationError in exception.EntityValidationErrors)
 {
   foreach (var validationError in entityValidationError.ValidationErrors)
   {
     object value = null;
     try { value = entityValidationError.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(validationError.PropertyName); }
     catch (System.Exception exception) { value = null; }

     message.AppendLine(validationError.PropertyName + ": " + validationError.ErrorMessage + " (VALUE: " + (value ?? "-") + ")");
  }
}

return message.ToString();
// and i get "AValue: The AValue field is required. (VALUE: -) so that value item is null
```

I'm pretty stumped at this point, just can't figure out why it looks fine during the try but still throws a validation error message.  Is there anything else I can add to see if there is something else going on there?  Or any other recommended troubleshooting steps?

Comment: what is the database type of AValue?

Comment: I would make sure that the list of entities you are pulling, none of them have NULL for Avalue.

Comment: AValue is a string (nvarchar(150) in the database)

Comment: when i pull the data out of the database it has an existing value "USER1"

Answer (score 2):

Please verify that the `Item.AValue` is set up properly in the Entity Framework dataset definition so that it is pointing to the `AValue` column in the relevant database table. If for some reason this is missing, then setting it in code would not cause it to be updated in the Db, which could lead to this error.

Comment: It looks good from the Entity Framework side (it was a database first creation of the model) ... I have saved values before using similar code ... I'm sure I've done something just slightly off, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains some small syntax mistakes:

```
var item = (from i in entities.Item
           where i.Id = 1
           select i).First();
```

should be (double == sign)

```
var item = (from i in entities.Item
           where i.Id == 1
           select i).First();
```

Also:

```
item.AValue = "NewValue"
```

should be followed by a ";" sign.

I've recreated a small example that works:

Object class:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework context class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> items { get; set; }

    public Context()
        : base("Demo")
    {
    }
}
```

On the first run, adds an item in the database:

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
    Item stud = new Item() { Name = "Name" };
    ctx.items.Add(stud);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now, replace the code above with the following code:

```
try
{
    var entities = new Context();
    var item = (from i in entities.items
                where i.Id == 1
                select i).First();
    item.Name = "NewValue";
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException exception)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was that there was a sub-object on my item that also had a property of AValue and this was the one that was throwing the exception.

Is there some way (via the DbEntityValidationException) to report on what object it is as well?